# Slideable action on tap

Tags: android, flutter

I have a listview using slideable, how to make it when the slideable icon is taped it will run a function?

```
 IconSlideAction(
       caption: 'View',
       color: Colors.grey.shade200,
       icon: Icons.info_outline,
       onTap: () => anotherFunction(),
   ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the `IconSlideAction` in a `GestureDetector`

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () => anotherFunction(),
  child: IconSlideAction(
   caption: 'View',
   color: Colors.grey.shade200,
   icon: Icons.info_outline,
 ), // IconSlideAction
)
```

Please see full documentation on [GestureDetector](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)

Comment: I try to test with onTap: () {print ("a"); } but there is no response...

Comment: @AgisRHerdiana Please show more code so i can recreate the issue. I tested the app and its working